# How to check in VBA if an ID + a condition is unique

Tags: arrays, vba

I am totally a newbie with VBA *(as well as with StackOverflow!)*, I learned the skills I needed quickly, but I have encountered a problem.

My Excel file looks like this currently:

```
|    ID    | ... |  Condition  | ...
|id1       | ... |default      | ...
|id1       | ... |One; Two     | ...
|id2       | ... |default; Two | ...
|id3       | ... |One, default | ...
```

And I need to check several things. So far, no problem. Except for one thing: how can I check that if a specific ID has a specific condition (let's say, id1 has the condition "Two"), there must not be another line with the same ID and the same condition again.

**Specific aspects:**

- Except for the mandatory "default" condition, the program should not know what are the different conditions, nor how many conditions there will be.
- I cannot change the Excel file used in my company.
- Each ID has at least the "default" condition (I know how to check that), but apart from default, can have from 0 to possibly a lot of conditions (will never probably be more than 10, but well...).

I would know how to do so with known conditions, creating an array for each condition, going through each line, adding the ID in the array of the said condition except if it already exists. Unfortunately, I do not meet those requirements.

## Update

To clarify: What I call an unique combination is an id, and one condition. In the Excel sample I gave, we only have unique combinations: id1+default, id1+One, id1+Two, id2+default, id2+Two, etc... The following sample contains a problem that I need to find:

```
|    ID    | ... |  Condition  | ...
|id1       | ... |default      | ...
|id1       | ... |One; Two     | ...
|id2       | ... |default; Two | ...
|id2       | ... |One, default | ...
```

Here, there is twice the combination "id2+default". That's an error my VBA program must find.

Comment: What makes a combination of ID and condition **unique**? Given two rows with `id = 1 | Condition = One` and `id = 1 | Condition = One; Two` are they considered unique each? I think this could considerably influence the approach taken.

Comment: @Inarion, No, those lines contains an existing pair: id1 and the condition One. The pair ID+condition has to be unique. A pair would be "id1;One", or "id1;default", or "id1;Two". These are unique combinations. If on one line, there is "id1 ... default; One" and, in another line, "id1 ... One;Two", there is a problem since there is twice "id1;One", and I need to spot such errors. Going to edit to clarify.

Comment: Excel Power Query might be an easier alternative https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gilraviv/2015/11/08/split-and-unpivot-comma-separated-values/

Comment: @Slai If I understood well enough, this implies a modification of the worksheet. This is something I cannot do unfortunately. But still, thanks for your input !

Comment: not really .. the query can be in a separate book and use the original as external datasource. I have much more experience with VBA, but I find Power Query easier for data transformation and aggregation.

Comment: @Slai Huh, that's certainly an aspect of Excel I've not yet delved into. Time to change that. :D

Comment: @Slai In that case, I will learn about this as well. it looks super-powerful. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat simple approach to check for uniqueness is the usage of a dictionary. (Add a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your project to get IntelliSense for it. If you don't want that reference, use the commented-out declaration.)

```
Dim D As Scripting.Dictionary
' Dim D as Object
Set D = New Scripting.Dictionary
' Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim K As String
K = GenerateKeyString()
If D.Exists(K) Then
    ' Uniqueness violated
    ' your code here...
Else
    ' Add key with empty content, as the value is not important to only check for uniqueness
    D.Add K, vbNullString
End If
```

The `GenerateKeyString()` function would return something like `ID1_ConditionOne` - how exactly this string looks is up to you. It's only important that its creation is consistent.

---

Let me try a rough sketch that you can improve upon:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindNonUniqueRows()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetNameHere")
    Dim D As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set D = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim StartRow As Long, CondCol As Long, IdCol As Long
    StartRow = 1    ' Starting row of your data
    IdCol = 1       ' Index column
    CondCol = 3     ' Condition column

    Dim r As Long
    r = StartRow
    ' Loop over each row until encountering an empty cell in the ID column
    Do While Ws.Cells(r, IdCol) <> vbNullString

        Dim Id As String
        Id = Ws.Cells(r, IdCol)
        ' Loop over each condition to add the ID/Condition pair to the dictionary
        Dim cond As Variant
        For Each cond In Split(Ws.Cells(r, CondCol), ";")

            ' Trim the string to avoid complications with leading or trailing blanks
            Dim condTrim As String
            condTrim = Trim(cond)

            Dim UniqueKey As String
            UniqueKey = GenerateKeyString(Id, condTrim)

            If D.Exists(UniqueKey) Then

                ' Uniqueness violated
                ' your code here...
                MsgBox "Combination of ID '" & Id & "' and condition '" & condTrim & "' already exists!"

            Else

                ' Add key with empty content, as the value is not important to only check for uniqueness
                D.Add UniqueKey, vbNullString

            End If

        Next cond
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function GenerateKeyString(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Condition As String) As String
    GenerateKeyString = Id & "_" & Condition
End Function
```

Note that you can directly iterate over the elements of the implicitly by `Split()` generated StringArray, without the need to first assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input ! It contains a lot of notions I have yet to experience with VBA. Gonna try to implement that and keep you updated to accept the answer. :)

Comment: @superpg I added some more or less complete code which you can further adapt. See if this helps you out! (The existence of the `GenerateKeyString` function is questionable at the moment. But if the algorithm to generate the string gets more complex, it's certainly a good idea to have that code in its own function.)

Comment: That is simply crazy, way more than a rough sketch. I was adapating your first answer, so I will continue to do that since I think that it makes me learn better, but I have to say how impressed I am with this, it can be a wonderful help. Thank you very much !

Comment: I agree - the best way to learn is getting to the solution yourself. :) (And you learn even more if you can afterwards explain that solution to someone.)